# Limiting value of $\dfrac{1}{m}\mathrm{tr}(FAF^\top (FBF^\top)^{-1})$, where $F$ has iide $N(0,1)$ entries and $A,B$ are deterministic

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices, statistical-physics, free-probability

Let $F=F_{m,d}$ be a random $m \times d$ matrix with iid entries from $N(0,1)$. Let $A=A_d$ and $B=B_d$ be deterministic $d \times d$ positive-definite matrices. In case it helps, it may be assumed that

- $A$ and $B$ are diagonal.
- $A$ and $B$ are diagonal with eigenvalues given by $a_i \asymp i^{-\beta_1}$ and $b_i \asymp i^{-\beta_2}$, for some constants $\beta_1,\beta_2 \gt 1$.
- $A$, $B$, or (inclusive) $AB^{-1}$ has limiting spectral density (LSD) in the limit $d \to \infty$.

> **Question 1.** What is the limiting value of $\dfrac{1}{m}\mathrm{tr}(FAF^\top (FBF^\top)^{-1})$ in the limit $m,d \to \infty$ such that $d/m \to \gamma \in (1,\infty)$ ?

> **Question 2.** Same as **Question 1**, but with $F$ uniform over the orthogonal group $FF^\top = I_m$.

Note that if $A=B$, then the sought-for limit is $1$.

### Observation

If $A$ and $B$ are aligned in the sense that they have the same eigenvectors, with eigenvalues $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots \ge a_d$ and $b_1 \ge b_2 \ge \ldots \ge b_d$ respectively, and $F$ is as in **Question 2**, then it is easy to see that
$$
\dfrac{1}{m}\mathrm{tr}(FAF^\top (FBF^\top)^{-1}) \overset{D}{=} \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{a_{\pi(i)}}{b_{\pi(i)}},
$$

where $\pi$ is a uniformly random permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,d\}$.

Furthermore, it's not hard to then deduce that
$$
\mathbb E\, \left[\dfrac{1}{m}\mathrm{tr}(FAF^\top (FBF^\top)^{-1})\right] = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{a_i}{b_i}.
$$